# my .live function not firing and giving me error using jquery 1.10.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

here is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/converter/Temperature.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/converter/TemperatureContents.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
alert("fgfgf"); 


});

</script>


</head>
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="converterListPage" data-theme="b">

   <div data-role="header">
    <h1>UNIT CONVERTER</h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">


       <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
       <li><a href="#"  id="tempButton">TEMPERATURE</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">WEIGHT</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">CURRENCY CONVERTER</a></li>
       </ul>


   </div>
 </div>
 <div data-role="page" id="temperatureContents" data-theme="e">
   <div data-role="content">
    <p>sdfsdsdsds</p>
   </div>
 </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Temperature.js

```
$('#converterListPage').live('pageinit', function() {

alert("converter list page");
$("#tempButton").off('click').on('click',function() 
{
  //$.mobile.changePage("#temperatureContents",null,true,true);
  alert("button clicked");
});

});
```

getting error on this line:

```
$('#converterListPage').live('pageinit', function()
```

and the error is:

> 07-31 11:01:42.405: E/Web Console(730): TypeError: Result of expression '$('#converterListPage').live' [undefined] is not a function. at file:///android_asset/www/js/converter/Temperature.js:10
>   after using on :

```
yes now there is no error: but when putting this line in DOM READY: 



$(document).ready(function()
{
alert("fgfgf"); 

$("#tempButton").off('click').on('click',function() 
{
 // $.mobile.changePage("#temperatureContents",null,true,true);
  alert("button clicked");
});
```

its working but when putting in temperature.js its not firing event :

```
$('#converterListPage').on('pageshow', function() {

alert("converter list page");
$("#tempButton").off('click').on('click',function() 
{
 // $.mobile.changePage("#temperatureContents",null,true,true);
  alert("button clicked");
});

});
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.ready` in JQM.

Answer (score 1):

Function live is deprecated and don't exist in a jQuery 1.8+ but you were already been told that so I am not going to explain with more details.

Regarding your new page event handling, you will need to use delegated handling, currently this is a proper way of handling page events.

Change this:

```
$('#converterListPage').live('pageinit', function() {
    alert("converter list page");
    $("#tempButton").off('click').on('click',function() {
        alert("button clicked");
    });
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#converterListPage',function() {
    alert("converter list page");
    $(document).on('click',"#tempButton",function() {
        alert("button clicked");
    });
});
```

Working **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/66/

Few notes:

- Page event is bound to the document object, in this case it don't care if page **`#converterListPage`** exist or don't exist but it will propagate to it at a point when that page becomes available in the DOM.
- I have removed .off('click') because you don't need it in case of pageinit, it will trigger only once. In case of other page events (like pagebeforeshow) use this line for your click event:

  ```
   $(document).off('click',"#tempButton").on('click',"#tempButton",function() {
  ```

One other thing, if this page is not your initial page then your javascript is going to be discarded. This is because jQuery Mobile strips every subsequent page of its HEAD content.

If this is the case read this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)** to find out how to solve it. If you have questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Since `.live()` is **deprecated** use `.on()` instead like

```
$('#converterListPage').on('pageinit', function()
```

And makesure that you put this in document ready itself..

Comment: yes now there is no error: but when putting this line in DOM READY:

Comment: I told like that only

Comment: how can i write code for button click inside pageshow but my pageshow event is not firing

Answer (score 0):

`.live` event handler removed in jQuery 1.10  Use `$('#converterListPage').on('pageinit', function()`